# OnClickListener within a fragment makes the application stops

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm using OnClick inside a TableRow in the Java file I'm using OnClickListener but when I run the application and try to get to fragment the application stops.

I want to do that by clicking the TableRow which is within the fragment open to a new activity.

This is the Java code file:

```
package com.hello.turidf;

import com.hello.turidf.R;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TabsIndexM001Help extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.m_001_help, container, false);

    Button openmap = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_map);
    openmap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootView) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), M001MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

}
```

This is the XML code file (fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
.......>

    <TableLayout
    .......>

        <TabelRow
        android:onClick="open_m001_map"
        ....>
            ........
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollBiew>
```

This is the logcat:

```
12-22 18:53:38.862: E/dalvikvm-heap(2783): ooh, a big allocation 3240000.
12-22 18:53:42.926: W/dalvikvm(2783): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 11264: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
12-22 18:53:58.421: W/dalvikvm(2783): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at com.hello.turidf.TabsIndexM001Help.onCreateView(TabsIndexM001Help.java:21)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at     android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1766)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1901)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:848)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:872)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:872)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:872)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:872)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1695)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1679)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2196)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1880)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3717)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
12-22 18:53:58.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 18:54:13.876: W/dalvikvm(2985): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 11264: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
```

Comment: this layout xml file doesnt tell us much when you give us like few percent of the whole file (and its important)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast `ImageView` to `Button`.

```
Button openmap = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_map);
```

Shange this line with

```
ImageView openMap = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_map);
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't keep 'onClick' attribute in xml file if you use SetOnClickListener in java code. In you case,it's enough to call a function named "open_m001_map" in you java code.

So you have two options.
1. Give 'onClick' attribute in xml code and create a function for it as follows.

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRowOne"
        android:onClick="open_m001_map">
.....
</TableRow>
```

Inside java code of fragment give like this.

```
public void open_m001_map(){
    Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),secondActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

2. Second method is remove 'onClick' from xml file and do as below;

In xml file,

```
<TableRow
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  adroid:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/tableRowOne"
  android:onClick="">
```

In java code,

```
TableRow tableRowOne=(TableRow)view.findViewById(R.id.tableRowOne);

tableRowOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),secondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

'secondActivity' is the name of activity that you want to open.

Comment: I've done a mistake. In first method you have to add the function to MainActivity java code and it should be like this,
    public void rowTwoClick(View view) {
          Intent i=new Intent(this,secondActivity.class);
          startActivity(i);
    }

However, I recommend you to use the second method.